# Find a tight frame of exponentials for $L^2(T)$, where $T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a triangle with vertices $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(-1,0)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Find a tight frame of exponentials for $L^2(T)$, where $T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a triangle with vertices $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(-1,0)$.

Normally, I would do is find a matrix representation and then set the elements of the diagonal equal to each other and then set the other elements of the diagonal equal to zero. How would I do it in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a Parseval frame is the image of an orthonormal basis under orthogonal projection from some larger Hilbert space. So, the following approach can be taken.

1. The exponentials $\{\exp(\pi i mx+2\pi i ny):m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ form an orthonormal basis for the rectangle $R = [-1,1]\times [0,1]$.
2. There is a natural projection from $L^2(R)$ onto $L^2(T)$, namely restriction to $T$.

Comment: So essentially we just need to find the orthonormal basis of the exponentials and thats it?

Comment: Yes, an orthonormal basis of exponentials on any domain containing the triangle.

Comment: How did you figure out that it needed to be $\pi imx+2\pi iny$?

Comment: Did you do separation of variables for Laplace equation in a rectangle? It's essentially the same thing. These are the eigenfunctions for the Laplacian with periodic boundary conditions. For a rectangle $a\times b$ I would use $\exp((2\pi i m/a) x +(2\pi i n/b) y)$.

Comment: How would I do a separation of variables for this problem?